# docker- The framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '5.0.0' was not found. - No frameworks were found

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have created a sample .NETCORE web API, and I'm trying to deploy to docker, I get below errors, could some one help on how to resolve this.
Below screenshot of docker file and error from Visual Studio code
docker file
docker file content[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQf9q.png)

List of asp.net core runtimes Installed in my local machine

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAWWU.png]

Comment: can someone guide me on query please

Comment: When you build the docker image, please use the `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0` as the runtime, instead of the `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:5.0`. Reference: [Docker images for ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/docker/building-net-docker-images?view=aspnetcore-5.0#build-and-deploy-manually) and [The framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '5.0.0' was not found](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/29611).

Comment: Hi Zhi, I have used mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS runtime as suggested, but didnot work out, I still get error "It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '5.0.0' was not found.
  - No frameworks were found.

You can resolve the problem by installing the specified framework and/or SDK.

The specified framework can be found at:
  - https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.AspNetCore.App&framework_version=5.0.0&arch=x64&rid=debian.10-x64"

Comment: From the image, it seems that you have installed the 5.0.2 and 5.0.5 version runtime and SDK, try to change the version to these versions. Or you could try to install the 5.0.0 version SDK and runtime.

Comment: Thanks Zhi, I have Installed 5.0.0 version SDK and runtime, it worked .. Glad that u helped me

Answer (score 0):

[image]

From the screenshot, we can see you have installed the Asp.net Core 5.0.2 and 5.0.5 version runtime and SDK, without the Asp.net Core 5.0.0 Version.

So, to fix this issue, you could install the Asp.net Core 5.0.0 version SDK and runtime. Or you could use the existing Asp.net core version to create docker image.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to pull a new version for the dotnet image .
check these:

[link1](https://www.pmichaels.net/2021/12/04/docker-error-with-net-6-runtime-image/)

[Link2](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-runtime)

Answer (score 0):

My case was with docker because the message was always: the framework 'microsoft aspnetcore app version '5.0 0 was not found at runtime so in the document .Dockerfile add
=> FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:5.0 AS base
and
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
was working with workerservice and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR**:  When you use Visual Studio to Build a Docker Image for you automatically, sometimes the BASE Image that is used is not always correct.  This really should be something that Visual Studio Fixes. Change the image to FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base to resolve.

Rational:  There are many runtimes available, which contain more or less features to keep the binary small.  If the wrong runtime is chosen, the error listed above will happen. Find the base image being used in your Docker File and change it to the following:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
```